# "focus follows mouse" does not respect the window orders while closing a window

Tags: unity, 12.04, mouse, focus

In `gconf-editor`, `apps>metacity>general` I have set up 
"focus_mode" to "sloppy" and "auto-raise" to "false".

Now the focus follows the mouse. Anyway, when I have several windows opened, and I close the one on top, the window immediately under the "x" button raises.

I would like that the system respect the "order" of the windows instead.

Here is an example: I have a top window, a middle window, and a background terminal:

[image: before clicking]

If I close the window, I obtain the terminal on top, instead of the middle window. This happens because the terminal is just under the "x" of the top window.

[image: after clicking]

It was more logical (and if was like that, before Unity), to obtain the middle window on top instead of of the terminal, like that:

[image: what I wish]

This is particularly annoying with maximized background applications. Someone knows how to obtain (again) this effect? it is particular disturbing if there is a maximized application and several little windows on it.

Moreover, if focus-follows-mouse is enabled, it is possible to remove/rename desktop icons **only** if the desktop is completely free.

Comment: You have filed a bug on this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/focus-follows-mouse/+bug/958432

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest also turning off `/apps/metacity/general/auto_raise`.

The focus will still go to the "other" window, but the windows' stacking order remains the same, which makes it easier to refocus on the (new) fully exposed top window (just move the mouse over it, of course).

Comment: I would prefer the "middle" window to take focus, and either _click_ to focus and raise the bottom terminal, or move out/in to focus the bottom terminal without raising it. Is this possible?